# Does Mongodb support search suggester like Azure Cognitive Search?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Does anyone know whether Mongodb query can perform the search suggester like Azure Cognitive search ? For example if I want to search for all the name starting with "Kin", the result will display 5 suggester search name starting from Kin?

Comment: Do you mean something like using `$regex` in this [mongoplayground.net example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/d65M4LBX9_-)?

Comment: I think this is more equivalent to like statement right? I know MongoDB will return the result if we give some letter hint, sort of like statement in SQL. But I am looking for actually the suggester to the front end like ACS (Azure Cognitive Search) can provide. Like when you type "Kin" form the search box, it will give you suggester with names starting from Kin (limit 5 records for example) and you pick one of then record and do the real search. I know SQL server can not provide that functionality. Not sure whether MongoDB can provide something like that.

Comment: StackOverflow is for asking questions about programming.  IDK ACS, but it sounds like a layer on top of a database.  MongoDB is a database you can query, but IDK if there is a similar ACS-like layer available for it.  I'm guessing ACS determines the type (int, text, etc.) of what you type and then wildcard searches indexes of the appropriate type in its underlying database.  You could create that for MongoDB.  IDK if its already available though.

Comment: ACS is not querying directly through mongodb. It is creating a datasource point to mongodb and constantly updating it is own data pool to run ACS query against its own data pool which pushed from mongodb. I just want to find out whether mongodb has the query ability to get the same functionality.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.  The way you describe ACS, it's a front-end to MongoDB and provides a search service.  That's what virtually all MongoDB-backed apps do.

Comment: ACS (Azure Cognitive search) is not search through Mongodb directly. It grabs the data from Mongdb and build its own data source and search from his own data source using the query belongs to ACS only.

Comment: Yes, caching layers can be useful.